# The classic problem with nvidia drivers - GeForce 820M - Login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, bug-reporting, 20.04

Before making this question, I've searched and found no solution.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and my graphics card is GF820M (GF117M).

Currently I'm using the intel one, but everytime I try to install the recommended one which is nvidia-340, I get stuck at login page. I introduce my password and just loops back to the login page and asks me for password once again. But if I try to login to Xubuntu desktop (which I have also installed), I can do it, then I change the driver to the open source one again.

I've also tried to the use proprietary driver from here: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

But happens the same, whether I try the 390 or 430, which are the long-lived branch releases.

Any ideas as a solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: updated to 19.10, same issue happening

Comment: updated to 20.04 beta, same

Answer (score 0):

**TMP** workaround: Try to install a different GUI/Deskop, like (Just for example) LXDE (`sudo apt-get install lxde`)

Until it's solved; you maybe could use this(or another) desktop env.

Regards.